# using google oauth2.0 with react, express application

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm using react as a frontend and express.js as a backend API server.  My application should be used by users who have google emails. So I want to use Google OAuth for my app login.

I wonder how can I connect all of these react, express server, google OAuth. Are there any good resources explaining this?

user login with google OAuth, and if the user logged in the app, and a user can contact personnel data in express.js server. how can I deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have spent some time figuring this out. It is not well documented so I wrote this article. https://medium.com/@maartendebaecke2/mern-stack-implementing-sign-in-with-google-made-easy-9bfdfe00d21c

It shows you how you can use passport.js and the passport-google-oauth2
strategy to register a user, start a session and save that user in your database. It also contains some code for a styled "sign in with Google" button.

Comment: Wow, I've never seen this responses before. @M.DeBaecke entirely wrote his own post for answering this question. Thanks a lot

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.